# What is the derivative of Shannon's Entropy?

Tags: python, numpy, data-science, derivative, entropy

I have the following simple python function that calculates the entropy of a single input X according to Shannon's Theory of Information:

```
import numpy as np

def entropy(X:'numpy array'):
  _, frequencies = np.unique(X, return_counts=True)
  probabilities  = frequencies/X.shape[0]
  return -np.sum(probabilities*np.log2(probabilities))

a = np.array([1., 1., 1., 3., 3., 2.])
b = np.array([1., 1., 1., 3., 3., 3.])
c = np.array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])

print(f"entropy(a): {entropy(a)}")
print(f"entropy(b): {entropy(b)}")
print(f"entropy(c): {entropy(c)}")
```

With the output being the following:

```
entropy(a): 1.4591479170272446
entropy(b): 1.0
entropy(c): -0.0
```

However, I also need to calculate the derivative over `dx`:

> d entropy / dx

This is not an easy task since the main formula

> -np.sum(probabilities*np.log2(probabilities))

takes in `probabilities`, not `x` values, therefore it is not clear how to differentiate over `dx`.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Comment: You may find your answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/109306) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2822547) (this was a result of an Internet search; I am not an expert in the area).

Comment: @anatolyg Thank you for the reply, sadly none of the links provide the answer, the first discusses how to find max-entropy, the second derives relative to `p` (over `d  probability`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to use [finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Relation_with_derivatives) to compute the derivative numerically.

In this context, we can define a small constant to help us compute the numerical derivative. This function takes a one-argument function and computes its derivative for input `x`:

```
ε = 1e-12
def derivative(f, x):
    return (f(x + ε) - f(x)) / ε
```

To make our work easier, let us define a function that computes the innermost operation of the entropy:

```
def inner(x):
    return x * np.log2(x)
```

Recall that the derivative of the sum is the sum of derivatives. Therefore, the real derivative computation takes place in the `inner` function we just defined.

So, the numerical derivative of the entropy is:

```
def numerical_dentropy(X):
    _, frequencies = np.unique(X, return_counts=True)
    probabilities = frequencies / X.shape[0]
    return -np.sum([derivative(inner, p) for p in probabilities])
```

Can we do better? Of course we can! The key insight here is the product rule: `(f g)' = fg' + gf'`, where `f=x` and `g=np.log2(x)`. (Also notice that `d[log_a(x)]/dx = 1/(x ln(a))`.)

So, the analytical entropy can be computed as:

```
import math
def dentropy(X):
    _, frequencies = np.unique(X, return_counts=True)
    probabilities = frequencies / X.shape[0]
    return -np.sum([(1/math.log(2, math.e) + np.log2(p)) for p in probabilities])
```

Using the sample vectors for testing, we have:

```
a = np.array([1., 1., 1., 3., 3., 2.])
b = np.array([1., 1., 1., 3., 3., 3.])
c = np.array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])

print(f"numerical d[entropy(a)]: {numerical_dentropy(a)}")
print(f"numerical d[entropy(b)]: {numerical_dentropy(b)}")
print(f"numerical d[entropy(c)]: {numerical_dentropy(c)}")

print(f"analytical d[entropy(a)]: {dentropy(a)}")
print(f"analytical d[entropy(b)]: {dentropy(b)}")
print(f"analytical d[entropy(c)]: {dentropy(c)}")
```

Which, when executed, gives us:

```
numerical d[entropy(a)]: 0.8417710972707937
numerical d[entropy(b)]: -0.8854028621385623
numerical d[entropy(c)]: -1.4428232973189605
analytical d[entropy(a)]: 0.8418398787754222
analytical d[entropy(b)]: -0.8853900817779268
analytical d[entropy(c)]: -1.4426950408889634
```

As a bonus, we can test whether this is correct with an [automatic differentiation](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html) library:

```
import torch

a, b, c = torch.from_numpy(a), torch.from_numpy(b), torch.from_numpy(c)

def torch_entropy(X):
    _, frequencies = torch.unique(X, return_counts=True)
    frequencies = frequencies.type(torch.float32)
    probabilities = frequencies / X.shape[0]
    probabilities.requires_grad_(True)
    return -(probabilities * torch.log2(probabilities)).sum(), probabilities

for v in a, b, c:
    h, p = torch_entropy(v)
    print(f'torch entropy: {h}')
    h.backward()
    print(f'torch derivative: {p.grad.sum()}')
```

Which gives us:

```
torch entropy: 1.4591479301452637
torch derivative: 0.8418397903442383
torch entropy: 1.0
torch derivative: -0.885390043258667
torch entropy: -0.0
torch derivative: -1.4426950216293335
```